# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-sass

When I start my react project in Fedora 32 using command `yarn start`, it shows error like this:

```
./src/style/base.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/style/base.scss)
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

My current node version is:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/react-admin% nvm list
        v8.17.0
       v10.24.1
->     v16.13.0
        v17.2.0
         system
default -> 8 (-> v8.17.0)
```

I have tried different version of node but did not fix this problem, why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? I did not found any package dependencies of `node-sass` in the `package.json`, this is the package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "react-admin",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/compatible": "1.0.8",
        "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
        "antd": "^4.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "braft-editor": "^2.3.8",
        "echarts": "^4.4.0",
        "is-core-module": "2.2.0",
        "moment": "2.29.1",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-highlight-words": "0.17.0",
        "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",
        "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "screenfull": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-app-rewired start",
        "build": "CI=false && react-app-rewired build",
        "test": "react-app-rewired test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
            "node_modules/.bin/prettier --write",
            "git add"
        ],
        "src/**/*.{css,scss,less,json,html,md,markdown}": [
            "node_modules/.bin/prettier --write",
            "git add"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx": "^7.12.13",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.2",
        "customize-cra": "^0.8.0",
        "husky": "^3.0.9",
        "lint-staged": "^9.4.2",
        "sass": "1.37.0",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## First solution

Make sure your `node.js` version is not superior to the [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. If not downgrade it, and for that, you could use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm i -g n
n stable
# if one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 14
```

Then you would wanna use [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) package instead of [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), as it's deprecated. And for that run in your terminal:

```bash
npm uninstall node-sass --save
npm install sass --save
```

## Second solution

If you need or want `node-sass` for some reason, you should downgrade your `nodejs` version to like `v14`. For that you can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n 14
# if one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 14
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a common node-sass version compatibility problem with the Node version.

**Quick hack:**

Uninstall and reinstall `node-sass`, and it will find the missing binary for itself.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

**Permanent solution:**

If the issue is not resolved using the above commands, there may be a problem with your node version. Check that your node version supports node-sass version. Chose a stable node version and repeat the above commands to fix this issue.

Below is the compatibility table of the node with node-sass:-

```
NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module
Node 19     8.0                         111
Node 18     8.0                         108
Node 17     7.0+                        102
Node 16     6.0+                        93
Node 15     5.0+                        88
Node 14     4.14+                       83
Node 13     4.13+, <5.0                 79
Node 12     4.12+                       72
Node 11     4.10+, <5.0                 67
Node 10     4.9+, <6.0                  64
Node 8      4.5.3+, <5.0                57
Node <8     <5.0                        <57
```

If the issue is still not fixed, check the node-sass supported environment's list:-
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling node-sass while on the specific node version, I wanted to use for my project which in my case was Node V18 worked for me. thanks  @Balram Singh

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when deploying an already existing application.

And it helped me to downgrade the Node version.

When developing the application, **Node v14.19.2** was used, version **Node 16.18.0** was installed locally. node-sass has a dependency on the Node version according to the following scheme:

```
┌────┬─────────┬─────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│    │    A    │              B              │      C      │
├────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │ NodeJS  │ Supported node-sass version │ Node Module │
│  2 │ Node 19 │ 8.0+                        │ 111         │
│  3 │ Node 18 │ 8.0+                        │ 108         │
│  4 │ Node 17 │ 7.0+, <8.0                  │ 102         │
│  5 │ Node 16 │ 6.0+                        │ 93          │
│  6 │ Node 15 │ 5.0+, <7.0                  │ 88          │
│  7 │ Node 14 │ 4.14+                       │ 83          │
│  8 │ Node 13 │ 4.13+, <5.0                 │ 79          │
│  9 │ Node 12 │ 4.12+, <8.0                 │ 72          │
│ 10 │ Node 11 │ 4.10+, <5.0                 │ 67          │
│ 11 │ Node 10 │ 4.9+, <6.0                  │ 64          │
│ 12 │ Node 8  │ 4.5.3+, <5.0                │ 57          │
│ 13 │ Node <8 │ <5.0                        │ <57         │
└────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Based on the dependencies in the table, I installed Node version 14, which corresponds to the node-sass version from package.json and everything worked

```
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
```

I tried to change the node-sass version, but I didn't succeed. I was able to solve the problem only by downgrading the Node version

Sometimes, after changing the Node version, you need to run the command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```