# Failed to compile - trying to import index.scss into index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie and working on a reactjs project, now having the error below, can you please help me to solve it?

Failed to compile.

```
./src/styles/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/styles/index.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSrJT.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322975/15288641)