# node-gyp error with install npm node-sass - centos

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

I want to install node-sass on centos I got this error:

```
npm install node-sass


npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /***/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node /root/sops-logger/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory `/root/sops-logger/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/src -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/deps/openssl/config -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/deps/uv/include -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/deps/zlib -I/root/.node-gyp/16.17.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory `/root/sops-logger/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/root/sops-logger/node_modules/node-sass-middleware/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
```

node version: 16.17.0
npm version:  7.6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322912/error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment)

Answer (score 0):

node-sass has been deprecated so that's why you get the error

['node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594119/node-sass-usage-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-major-version)