# Failed to compile: Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to make react portfolio from freecodecamp. after all packages installed then change App.css to App.scss and then write some code, then show error like this:

```
"./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/App.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
Require stack:
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Tarikul\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js"
```

Then install "npm install node-sass":

```
Then show another error like this: "Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0."
```

I try to "npm install node-sass@4.0.0"
and also try: "npm install node-sass@8.0.0"
but problem is not fixed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322912/error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
}
```

If you are using Node.js 18.x, you need `node-sass@8.0.0`. Older packages will probably have an older dependency. You can force the dependency, don't worry about compatibility, `node-sass` is deprecated and hasn't changed in years - except to support newer Node.js versions.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `sass` instead

`node-sass`  has been deprecated and the new version is `sass`

So, you can do the following

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

No other changes needed